# Create textfield programmatically inside a graph subclass of NSView with swift in osx

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, graph, bar-chart

I am trying to add the axis text in a bar graph that I have created.

To do it, I used this code:

```
func showLabel (value: String, point: CGPoint) -> NSTextField {
    let label = NSTextField(frame: NSMakeRect(point.x, point.y, 100, 100))
    label.stringValue = "Axis Value"
    label.textColor = NSColor.blueColor()
    return label
}
```

But when calling this function inside the `drawrect{}` it didn't work, looks like something is missing. How can I display the axis labels? It should look like an excel bar chart, with title and this stuff in the axis.

The bar chart looks like this, but the number of columns can be different.

[bar chart in the playground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axDfe.png)

```
import Cocoa

class MyView: NSView {
override func drawRect(rect:NSRect){
    let pathRect = NSInsetRect(self.bounds, 1, 1)
    let path = NSBezierPath(rect: pathRect)

    path.lineWidth = 1
    NSColor.whiteColor().setFill()
    NSColor.blackColor().setStroke()
    path.fill()
    path.stroke()

    let bezierPath = NSBezierPath()

    // Create a rectangle that's inset by 15% on all sides
    let drawingRect = CGRectInset(self.bounds, self.bounds.size.width * 0.15,
                                  self.bounds.size.height * 0.15);
    // Define the points that make up the drawing
    let bottomLeft = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(drawingRect), CGRectGetMinY(drawingRect))
    let topRight = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(drawingRect), CGRectGetMaxY(drawingRect))
    let bottomRight = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(drawingRect),
                                  CGRectGetMinY(drawingRect))


    // Start drawing
    bezierPath.moveToPoint(topRight)
    bezierPath.lineToPoint(bottomLeft)
    bezierPath.lineToPoint(bottomRight)

    // Finish drawing by closing the path
    //bezierPath.closePath()

    // Set the colors and draw them
    //NSColor.redColor().setFill()
    NSColor.blackColor().setStroke()
    //bezierPath.fill()
    bezierPath.stroke()

    // Bars
    let bezierPathBarres = NSBezierPath()


    // m'haure d'inventar algo per fer aixo
    var arrayY = [100, 200, 300, 200, 100, 200, 300, 0, 35, 100, 200, 30]
    var arrayX = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

    for i in 0..<0 {
        arrayY.append(30+i)
    }
    //let arrayX = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]


    // entorn de X per barres
    let numeroDeBarres: CGFloat = CGFloat(arrayY.count)

    let espaiEntreBarres:CGFloat = 0.2 // estaria be fer-ho inspectable
    let ampladaEixX = self.bounds.width * (1 - 0.30)
    let espaiOcupatDelEixPerEspaisEntreBarres = ampladaEixX * espaiEntreBarres
    let espaiOcupatDelEixPerBarres = ampladaEixX * (1 - espaiEntreBarres)

    let espaiUnaBarra = espaiOcupatDelEixPerBarres / numeroDeBarres
    let espaiUnaSeparacio = espaiOcupatDelEixPerEspaisEntreBarres / (numeroDeBarres + 1)

    //entorn de Y per barres
    let valorBarraMax: CGFloat = CGFloat(arrayY.maxElement()!)
    let alçadaEixY = self.bounds.size.height * (1 - 0.30)
    let alçadaBarraMax = alçadaEixY * 0.90

    //creem un array d'alçades
    var arrayAlçades: [CGFloat] = []
    for i in 0..<arrayY.count {
        let valorBarra = CGFloat(arrayY[i])
        arrayAlçades.append(alçadaBarraMax * valorBarra / valorBarraMax)
    }


    for i in 0..<arrayY.count {

        // Define the points that make up the drawing
        //let bottomEspaiPunt = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(drawingRect), CGRectGetMinY(drawingRect))
        //let bottomBarraPuntEsquerra = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(drawingRect)+(espaiUnaSeparacio + espaiUnaBarra) * CGFloat(i) + espaiUnaSeparacio, CGRectGetMinY(drawingRect))
        //let topBarraPuntEsquerra = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(drawingRect)+(espaiUnaSeparacio + espaiUnaBarra) * CGFloat(i) + espaiUnaSeparacio, CGRectGetMinY(drawingRect) + arrayAlçades[i])
        //let topBarraPuntDreta = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(drawingRect)+(espaiUnaSeparacio + espaiUnaBarra) * CGFloat(i) + espaiUnaBarra, CGRectGetMinY(drawingRect) + arrayAlçades[i])
        //let bottomBarraPuntDreta = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(drawingRect)+(espaiUnaSeparacio + espaiUnaBarra) * CGFloat(i) + espaiUnaBarra, CGRectGetMinY(drawingRect))

        let rect = CGRect(x: CGRectGetMinX(drawingRect)+(espaiUnaSeparacio + espaiUnaBarra) * CGFloat(i) + espaiUnaSeparacio, y: CGRectGetMinY(drawingRect), width: espaiUnaBarra, height: arrayAlçades[i])

        let path = NSBezierPath(rect:rect)
        bezierPathBarres.appendBezierPath(path)
        // Start drawing
        //bezierPathBarres.moveToPoint(bottomBarraPuntEsquerra)
        //bezierPathBarres.lineToPoint(topBarraPuntEsquerra)
        //bezierPathBarres.lineToPoint(topBarraPuntDreta)
        //bezierPathBarres.lineToPoint(bottomBarraPuntDreta)

        // Adding
        let text = showLabel(String(arrayX[i]), point: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(drawingRect)+(espaiUnaSeparacio + espaiUnaBarra) * CGFloat(i) + espaiUnaSeparacio + espaiUnaBarra / 2 , CGRectGetMinY(drawingRect) - 0.15 / 2 * self.bounds.size.height))
        self.addSubview(text)

        // Finish drawing by closing the path
        //bezierPathBarres.closePath()
    }

    // Set the colors and draw them
    NSColor.greenColor().setFill()
    NSColor.blackColor().setStroke()
    bezierPathBarres.fill()

    if arrayY.count<20 {
        bezierPathBarres.stroke()
    }

}


func showLabel (valor: String, point: CGPoint) -> NSTextField {
    let label = NSTextField(frame: NSMakeRect(point.x, point.y, 100, 100))
    label.stringValue = "2"
    label.textColor = NSColor.blueColor()
    return label
}

// radiate the bbox out until the hashmarks are further out than the bounds

 }

let viewRect = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 100)
let myEmptyView = MyView(frame: viewRect)
```

Comment: Did you add it as a subview to the superview?

Comment: @RomanSausarnes I added the code to my question. I call the function inside class MyView: NSView { override func drawRect(rect:NSRect) { } }

Comment: Ups you are right! i didn't notice I was worried about this. Thanks @RomanSausarnes

Comment: You are only creating the NSTextField in showLabel. You need to add it to MyView by self.addSubview(label)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the label as a subview of the view that will contain it:

```
let label = showLabel(...)
self.addSubview(label)
```

Try that and see if it works. BTW, you shouldn't put this code in `drawRect`. It will end up adding a new label every time the view is redrawn.

Comment: yes! i just see it! thanks, I was going to post it too! And how could i do it?, because my view will redraw itself several times.

Comment: You could override one of the initializers and add the label there, or perhaps override `awakeFromNib`.